# The sum of two roots when their pairing is zero

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $(\Delta,(-,-))$ be a root system and $\alpha,\beta \in \Delta$ be s.t. $(\alpha,\beta) = 0$. Is it always true that
$$
\alpha + \beta, ~ \alpha - \beta \notin \Delta?
$$
This works for the $A$-series, but is there a general argument?

Comment: What is $\Delta$? Whatever it is, have you checked with the obvious (counter)example $B_2$ which contains the sums for all its orthogonal pairs of roots?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: There is no set of "the" simple roots of a  given root system. Every root can be made part of such a $\Delta$. So OP has to clarify if one set of simple roots $\Delta$ is chosen, and how $\alpha, \beta$ are supposed to be chosen w.r.t. that $\Delta$. Of course if both $\alpha, \beta \in \Delta$ then $\alpha \pm \beta \notin \Delta$ by the very definition of simple roots, totally regardless of what $(\alpha, \beta)$ is.

Comment: @TS: $\Delta = R$ I unfortunately used two notations for the same thing. This has been fixed now.

Comment: @TS: to address your complaint, there is no choice made of simple, or positive roots. This is a question about the whole root system.

Comment: Well then in $B_2$, you can take any pair of orthogonal $\alpha, \beta$, and both $\alpha \pm \beta \in \Delta$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg -- Actually, not any orthogonal pair. You want orthogonal pairs of short roots.

Comment: Then the conjecture is clearly wrong. If somebody puts this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a root system $R$ of type $B_2$, there are various pairs of short roots $\alpha, \beta$ with $(\alpha,\beta)=0$ but both $\alpha \pm \beta \in R$.

Comment: Just to have the term, which you of course know, written down, this behaviour is called "strong orthogonality".